# css position tricks for website header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please check this:

[image]

i am doing responsive web design and i have 100% with image slider. if i re-size my browser slider image height will change.

both slider and navigation wrap in my header, so i need to get header height when i responsive.

and also i need to both (navigation , and slider ) top:0px;

i think you can get some idea what i try to say.

```
<header>

<nav> <!-- my header main menu goes here --> </nav>

<div class="slider">
<!-- slider images goes here --> 
</div>

</header>

<div class="content">
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: You should separate slider and navigation into two different elements, why put the slider in the header if it acts as a background ?

Comment: read about `position` and `z-index` this will help you acheiving your goals.

Comment: Why do you set the need the slider top:0? It should just fall behind the navigation if the navigation is given a position: absolute; top: 0; if you leave sliders position the header height will be controlled by the slider height. You might need to give the navigation a z-index higher than the slider.

Comment: @Jérémy Dutheil , i have add my code , what i need to do. thank you

Comment: @MassivePenguin i have added my code bellow my question

Comment: @Last1Here , if i add position:absolute for both, i cant get my header height.

Comment: @Dishan TD thats what i said why do you need `position: absolute` for the slider? what i was meaning [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M85nu/)

Comment: a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M85nu/2/) of the example above with an image and responsive slider height

Answer (score 0):

do this in css:

```
html,body{
   height:100%;
}

header{
  background:blue;
  height: 100%;
  /*padding-bottom: 120px;*/ //<---remove this
}

nav{
   position:relative;
   top: 0;
   width: 960px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 2;
   background: red;
   height: 50px;
}

.slider{
   width:98%
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   margin: 0 auto;
   z-index: 1;
   background: green;
   height: 100%;
}
```

[**Try this**](http://jsbin.com/AZEcAFI/1/edit)

Comment: hi jai ,
thank you your answer,

if i add position:absolute; i cant get height for my header.then content goes up.

Comment: @Dilshan TD try with `relative`

Comment: @DishanTD see the updates and a jsbin link and see if this helps you.

Comment: actually thankx , no my header height need to equal for slider height. slider size will change in re-size window.as i think `header{height:auto;}` .

Comment: you can remove this also `padding-bottom: 120px;` from the header too.